# Class 'net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType' not found in AcceptSuite\create-an-accept-payment-transaction.php

Tags: php, authorize.net

I have tried the AcceptSuite, and getting the error as below

> Class 'net\authorize\api\contract\v1\MerchantAuthenticationType' not found in AcceptSuite\create-an-accept-payment-transaction.php

I have just cloned (git clone https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php.git) the repo and run the composer update.
I am trying to use AcceptSuite for making the transactions.

below is my code

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog.txt");

function createAnAcceptPaymentTransaction($request, $session)
{
    // Create a merchantAuthenticationType object with authentication details
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName($authnet_loginid);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey($authnet_transaction_key);
}
```

below is the code in composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
  "php": ">=5.6",
  "ext-curl": "*",
  "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8||~6.0",
  "authorizenet/authorizenet": ">=1.9.9 || <2.0" 
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: @JohnConde I have added my code.

Comment: @JohnConde edited the code. This is the code I have got from the repo it self. I just want to use it.

Comment: I don't get that error from this code. Are you sure your path to the autoload file is correct?

Comment: I have not made any changes in the code. this is what I got from the repo itself.
After cloning I have done the composer update as well

Comment: @JohnConde I have added the code in composer.json file as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using framework like laravel, you need to put the exact path where the sdk folder is installed.

```html
require 'publics/plugins/sdk-php/autoload.php';
  use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
  use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;
  
  define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");
```

otherwise, if you are using the framework, you can follow these steps to install authorize

https://codescompanion.com/authorize-net-payment-gateway-integration-with-laravel/

Comment: That's not true. They are including the vendor autoload file which is the correct way to do this.